# Data Binding to a LinkedList?

Tags: c#, wpf, linked-list, observablecollection, databound

**What Works:**

- Web service that manipulates an in-memory LinkedList (of strings).
- Clients can insert/add/remove/query the contents of the LinkedList.
- Web service is started from the command line (no UI).

**What I Would Like to Do:**

- Change the command line app to a WPF app.
- From the WPF app display the current state of the LinkedList.
- Data bind the UI control so any client actions are reflected in the display.

Speed is not a huge issue, as the WPF app is read-only and more informational.  I chose a LinkedList to support the needed client functionality.

I am having difficulty finding any tutorials and/or examples that can help.  Any suggestions on how I should approach this would be great.

Comment: Just curious: if speed is not an issue, why a LinkedList and not an `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Comment: I have taken your advice and switched to an ObservableCollection<T>, and so far, so good.  As I mentioned in a comment below, if I later need the performance and/or speed of the LinkedList solution, I will switch back.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear that it's working but it wasn't advice; it was a question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a new class called ObservableLinkedList and implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx).
- Give same methods in that class as LinkedList and internally forward all the methods to the contained linkedlist,
- but also fire INotifyCollectionChanged events so WPF can know that your linked list changed.

For WPF to know that a bound collection has changed; it has to implement INotifyCollectionChanged

OR

Just trigger collectionview to be refreshed everytime you update the linkedlist like the following

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ViewModel.TheCollectionProperty).Refresh();
```

Comment: +1: implementing a LinkedList that also implements INotifyCollectionChanged was how I was thinking of doing this one too.

Comment: This is what I was looking for (took a while to learn/implement).  Thanks!  BTW, though this works, I am going to simplify my solution to use the ObservableCollecton<T> that Erno suggested and switch to this if performance and/or functionality becomes an issue.